# How to compute the distance from the current polygon centroid to another in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, centroids

There is layer with polygons. I want to save in new field distance of every polygon's centroid to centroid of one particular polygon.

To do this I should write some expression like this:

```
distance(centroid($geometry), get_feature(6679)) # 6679 is feature id of some polygon
```

According to [weak documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) get_feature returns the first feature of a layer matching a given attribute value. Writing it like this

```
get_feature('id', 6679)
```

results into "Parsing Error: Function is called with wrong number of arguments".

Who knows the right way to get geometry of some polygon with given feature id?

Answer (score 4):

The function you are looking for is actually `getFeature` (at least in QGIS 2.8). It takes 3 arguments (hence your "Parsing Error") : the name of the layer, the name of the field, and the value of the field. So it would be something like `getFeature( 'your_layer', 'id', 6679 )`.

Additionnal point : you actually have to use `geometry(getFeature( ... ))` in your expression, because `distance` takes geometry arguments. In the end, you will have :

`distance( centroid($geometry), geometry(getFeature('your_layer', 'id', 6679)) )`

Answer (score 1):

Your answer, actually helped, but I didn't find a way to get feature by feature id. So I created new field `ID` containing feature id, expression is simple:

```
@row_number
```

And then solved my task

```
distance(centroid($geometry), centroid(geometry(getFeature(@layer_name, 'ID', 6609))))
```

Thanks!